# Get all wikipedia category list with each language using api?

Tags: list, api, categories, wikipedia

I want get all wikipedia categorys name with api.
i search it and find some way like dumb data or sql data but i want make it this with wikipedia api. Also i found it some great link for wikipedia tools like wmflabs.org but this tools not have my need.

i want use wikipedia api and result json data and get english wikipedia category name list. All categories content is here-> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Contents/Categories

i need same style category name lis data all other languages.

i find it some query but not enough like(find subcategorys in weapons category)-> https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php ?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Weapons

Is any solution have for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

All the categories belong to the `Category` namespace, that has id=14, so you can use [allpages API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Allpages) and filter by namespace using the `apnamespace` parameter. Here's an [example query](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&aplimit=5&apnamespace=14).